# Spring Boot: setting a PostgreSQL run-time parameter when database connection is open

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data

I am looking for the right way to set a [run-time parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) when a database connection is open. My run-time parameter is actually a time zone, but I think this should work for an arbitrary parameter.

I've found following solutions, but I feel like none of these is *the right thing*.

1. **JdbcInterceptor**

   Because Spring Boot has Apache Tomcat connection pool as default I can use [`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/JdbcInterceptor.html) to intercept connections.

   I don't think this interceptor provides a reliable way to perform a statement when connection is open. Possibility to intercept every statement provided by this interceptor is unnecessary to set a parameter that should be set only once.
2. **initSQL property**

   Apache's pooled connection has a build-in ability to initialise itself by a statement provided by `PoolProperties.initSQL` parameter. This is executed in `ConnectionPool.createConnection(...)` method.

   Unfortunately official support for this parameter has been [removed from Spring](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/jdbc/issues/1) and no equivalent functionality has been introduced since then.

   I mean, I can still use a datasource builder like in an example below, and then hack the property into a connection pool, but this is not a good looking solution.

   ```
   // Thank's to property binders used while creating custom datasource,
   // the datasource.initSQL parameter will be passed to an underlying connection pool.
   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }
   ```

   ## Update

   I was testing this in a Spring Boot 1.x application. Above statements are no more valid for Spring Boot 2 applications, because:

   1. Default Tomcat datasource was replaced by Hikari which supports `spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql` property. It's documentation says *Get the SQL string that will be executed on all new connections when they are created, before they are added to the pool.*
   2. It seems that similar property was reintroduced for Tomcat datasource as `spring.datasource.tomcat.init-s-q-l`.
3. **ConnectionPreparer & AOP**

   This is not an actual solution. It is more like an inspiration. The connection preparer was a mechanism used to initialise Oracle connections in [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext) project. This thing has [its own problems](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/issues/17) and is no more maintained but possibly can be used as a base for similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter is actually a time zone, why don't you find a way to set **this** property.

For example if you want to store or read a DateTime with a predefined timestamp the right way to do this is to set property `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` in hibernate `entityManager` or `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` in `application.properties`

Comment: I forget to mention that I am not using Hibernate. I am on Ebean, jOOQ and JdbcTemplate. Anyway, even in a Hibernate application the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` seems to not working for JdbcTemplate.

Comment: It seems it’s not possibile to do that. You have to pass on each query datetime with timezone